# Is there any Offline Map Libraries for PHP?

Tags: php, dictionary

is there any **offline map libraries** that can be used from PHP? I want to make an application which displays all data position of stations (with latitude and longitude) on a map.

But the user doesn't want this application connect to internet, so I can't use Google Maps as a solution. Do you know any offline map libraries that can mark position based latitute and longitude information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly does the application need to do. Render points on a map, or do Geocoding of addresses?

Comment: Just render points on a map. I have latitude and longitude data for each points.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to render graphical maps of anywhere on the globe, you're gonna need *a lot* of geographical data and a lot of storage (unless you're keeping the resolution low). For geographical data of the U.S., you can purchase bulk data sets (or obtain smaller free data sets) from certain commercial organizations, or try [GeoData.gov](http://gos2.geodata.gov/wps/portal/gos).

Once you've obtained your [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS) data set, you can use [Image_GIS](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GIS) to visualize the data. I haven't used the library, so I don't know how the results look, but that's one solution.

Comment: http://www.openstreetmap.org/ is another good source for the map data, or http://openmaps.eu/ for eastern european maps

Comment: I haven't heard openstreetmap.org before. Gonna take a look at it. Thank you

Comment: @Mark Baker
Have you ever put marker/poi on offline openstreetmap based on latitute and longitude?

Comment: I have already exported my country map from openstreetmap (in PNG format) but now, I'm confused to add marker or poi on it...:(

Comment: Not on maps from openstreetmap, no! Just on normal jpg files... and mapping long/lat to a pixel position on an image is a whole different question